# Payoffs in games with imperfect information can be different?

Tags: game-theory, information

I know that a game has imperfect information if there is an nonsingleton information set, and that defines a situation on which a player can't distinguish between the nodes in the information set. However, I'm wondering if, conceptually, it makes sense that the payoffs *can* be different, and still the player at the nonsingleton information set can't distinguish between the nodes. For example, consider an extensive form game with imperfect information like the following:

[image: game with a subgame with an infoset with two nodes]

Which appears in [Game Theory Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLWtcWPi84s&ab_channel=GameTheoryOnline). There is an information set with two nodes for player 1 after player 2 choses A or B. Why player 1 can't distinguish at which node she is by the payoffs of, say $l$? If she recognizes that the payoff of $(0,0)$ corresponds for $l$ after $A$ and $(2,4)$ for $l$ after $B$, doesn't this disambiguate the situation?

Comment: She moves before payoffs are realized, so she cannot use this payoff information.

Comment: Also, the title is about incomplete information, but the question is about imperfect information.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, my mistake, I meant "complete and imperfect".